# jackson provider not available when run application

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to test java application(have main method). I am using maven to add dependencies into my project. I am running application from IntelliJ IDE directly rather than creating a fat jar and then run. But somehow i unable to find JSON class at runtime and getting exception

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
at com.hospitality.component.visma.websocket.Test.<init>(Test.java:10)
at com.hospitality.component.visma.websocket.Test.main(Test.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

This project have a parent pom.xml file which have already included this jar.mvn dependecy:tree showing following jar list:

```
[INFO] Building visma-websocket-server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------
  -------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ visma-websocket-server ---
[INFO] com.hospitality.hp.components:visma-websocket-server:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.metro:webservices-rt:jar:2.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.metro:webservices-api:jar:2.3:provided
[INFO] |     \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2-b03:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.0:provided
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:compile
[INFO] +- com.hospitality.hp.components:jndi-tools:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO] \- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.8:provided
```

Can someone tell me how i can fix this as default scope is compile so why this is not available when i run my application in IDE? However in a  JunitTest run without any issue. Any idea how to fix this ?

-------------------------dependencyManagement---------------------------------

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Did you import your project to IDEA as a maven project?

Answer (score 0):

```
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.1:provided
```

Scope is `provided` so it is normal to have `NoClassDefFoundError`; should leave out the scope statement and use the default.

Comment: Yes this is showing as provided as because from parent its scope was provided. Can i convert this scope into compile in child pom ?

Comment: You can use a `dependencyManagement` section to handle this I think (in the pom of the consumer). Just add this section, add `jackson-databind` with the correct scope in it, and you should be fine.

Comment: Seems to be not working with dependencyManagement. I have added these Jsckson dependencies into dependencyManagement and remove from default dependencies tag and now it unable to resolve in project.

Comment: Can you please show this `dependencyManagement` section you've added? (it needs to be added in the pom of the project that threw this error, not in the parent; also, it needs to include jackson-databind in it; also, what does `dependency:tree` says now?) I've used this technique in the past to tell maven which version I want out of conflicting artifacts version, so it could be that is not working with regards to scope. Then can't you just include your artifact again in your pom, with the correct scope?

Comment: I updated my question with child pom.xml with dependencyManagement. From this dependencyManagement i unable to resolve dependency in intelliJ and its showing error

Comment: By adding jackson into dependencyManagement of child pom, dependency:tree showing nothing about jackson dependencies..

Comment: In this case I have no idea what's going on; I really did not expect to not see nothing at all after dependencyManagement; a wild guess is the fact that you did not included the version for those artifacts.
You can always just include another `dependency` for `jackson-databind ` and easily solve the problem if this is an option for you.

Comment: Ahh i find a reason why it was not working. It is because of 2 layer of parent in my module. I have move dependencyManagement into first parent layer and when add  dependency into child it is not showing into compile scope. This is my first time i used dependencyManagement Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: If `dM` didn't worked in child pom, then it wouldn't have worked in child pom even with 1 layer of parents, I suspect. If I were you, I'd fix the real problem, and I'd try again with `dM` in child pom, but with versions in place (perhaps parent pom really needs those dependencies with `scope=provided`)